# Something renames my vlan connection

Tags: systemd, udev, vlan

I am trying to create vlan interface. In /etc/network/interfaces I have:

```
auto lan.110
iface lan.110 inet manual
        vlan-raw-device lan
```

In dmesg I see

```
[    2.621534] igb 0000:05:00.0 lan: renamed from eth1
[    2.646276] igb 0000:02:00.0 wan: renamed from eth0
[    6.768520] rename4: renamed from lan.110
```

If first two renames is ok, third one is not desired one. Kernel have options "net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0". Ubuntu 16.04. What part of Linux renames my vlan and how I can avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely udev's job

The VLAN interface is matched with same rule as the Ethernet interface.

If simple systemd-networkd rule applied to a physical link:

```
[Match]
MACAddress=00:11:22:33:44:55

[Link]
Name=link1
```

Then it will be applied to all VLAN interfaces on same eth as they will have the same MAC address.
This will result in VLAN interfaces being renamed to `renameX`

The solution will be to add additional rules for VLANs or physical interfaces to match specific NIC. For my case `Path=pci*` keys were enough:

```
[Match]
MACAddress=00:11:22:33:44:55
Path=pci*

[Link]
Name=link1
```

For matching VLAN interfaces `Driver=*802.1Q*` key would be better

Comment: I had an existing rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`: `SUBSYSTEM=="net", ATTR{address}=="00:50:56:xx:xx:xx", NAME="eth0"`. Appending `, DRIVERS!="*802.1Q*"` prevented the rename for the VLAN interface.